# Rotating histogram horizontally in r

Tags: r, plot, histogram

Can anyone help me how to rotate histogram just by 90 degrees in r? I know there is an option (horiz=T) in boxplot but I have no idea if there is a similar one for the histogram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `ggplot2`, you can use `coord_flip()`:

```
    # here with @PKumar data
    x <- pmin(3, pmax(-3, stats::rnorm(50)))
    library(ggplot2)
    qplot(x, geom="histogram",binwidth = 0.3) + coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think you have to use hist with barplot to do it like below (its straight from documentation), you can check it here ?layout.

```
x <- pmin(3, pmax(-3, stats::rnorm(50)))
xhist <- hist(x, breaks = seq(-3,3,0.5), plot = FALSE)
barplot(xhist$counts, axes = TRUE, space = 0, horiz=TRUE, xlab= "Counts", ylab="Bins")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @PKumar. My data frame is in the range of -16.18 and 1019.93 with a median of 0.03. When I try to change the ylim (something in the range of -1 and 1), it gives me a line. Any idea how to adjust the y limit?

Comment: @SoheilKoushan, Its a good idea to put sample random records of your data with your question.